# How to use index column in many-to-many association in criteria in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3 with Java.

My POJOs classes are as follows:

**Teacher.java**

```
private long id;
private String teacherName;
private List<Student> students;
// getter-setter of all
```

**Student.java**

```
 private long id;
 private String studentName;

// getter-setter of both
```

**Teacher.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Teacher" table="teacher_master">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="long">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>

    <property column="teacher_name" name="teacherName" type="string" />

    <list name="students" cascade="refresh">
        <key column="teacher_id"/>
        <index column="student_position" type="integer"/>
        <one-to-many class="Student"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

**Student.hbm.xml** contains mappings for **id** & **studentName** properties.

My database structure looks like the following:

**teacher_master**

```
id  | teacher_name
----|--------------
1   | teacher1
2   | teacher2
```

**student_master**

```
id  | student_name  | teacher_id  | student_position
----|---------------|-------------|------------------
1   | student1      |      1      |      0
2   | student2      |      1      |      2
3   | student3      |      1      |      1
```

Now I want to fetch all Students attached to Teacher with id = 1, **in the order of student_position**.

I've written the following criteria:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
ids.add(1l);
ids.add(2l);
ids.add(3l);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
List<Student> students = criteria.list();
```

Here **students** will give me the records in order of the primary key that is 1,2,3.

I want these records to be in order of their **student_position** that is 1,3,2.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
     Long techId=1l;
     Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Student.class, "student");
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("student.teacherId", techId));
     criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("student.studentPosition"));
```

You cant query for object with criteria  If the field is not present in the model object. 
The Other way you can go with is hibernate native query.

```
    Long techId=1l;
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
           "select * from student_master s where s.teacher_id = :teacherId order by s.student_position")
            .addEntity(Student.class)
            .setParameter("teacherId", "techId");
             List result = query.list();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an ordering criterion, org.hibernate.criterion.Order

```
criteria.addOrder( Order.asc("yourPropertyName"));
```

You can also add more than one of these orderings.
Also see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) under 15.3

Comment: But **student_position** is not a property. It's just a column, whose value is handled by Hibernate.

Comment: Then you will have to make it a property. Criteria only refer to fields that are present in your class.

Comment: That I already know. But I can't make it a property as its value is handled by Hibernate.

Comment: I really don't see a reason why you could not add student_position to your Student.java class... but maybe I misunderstand something about your problem?

Comment: If I add student_position as property, I'm providing a scope where its value may be set or changed programmatically which is not desirable. value of student_position is maintained by Hibernate & I don't want to make it less restrictive.

Comment: Well... you're ofc right about that... maybe using a native SQL query would be the better solution for you then?